# can't create payment invoice without redirecting

Tags: python, api, paypal, payment

I want to accept money through paypal. I need to send the user a link and get paid. The approval_link link is being created successfully. But it is not possible to pay using the link. I log in using this link, click pay, but I am redirected to return_url. I don't want this, I want the user not to be redirected anywhere. You just need to take the money from him and that's it. My project is not a website and I don't have any pages where you can redirect the client. Help to create a payment form without redirecting the client to other pages. I thank you in advance for the attention you paid to my problem and I apologize for my English.

I will repeat briefly: we need a payment form without redirecting to other pages. Just get the money. Please help to configure the parameters of paypalrestsdk.Payment()

```
import paypalrestsdk

api = paypalrestsdk.set_config(
    mode="sandbox",
    client_id="XXX",
    client_secret="XXX")

token = api.get_access_token()

print(token)

payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"},

    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/process",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
    },

    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "RUB",
                "quantity": 1}]},
        "amount": {
            "total": "1.00",
            "currency": "RUB"},
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."}]})
create = payment.create()
if create:
  print("Payment created successfully")
else:
  print(payment.error)

for link in payment.links:
    if link.rel == "approval_url":
        # Convert to str to avoid Google App Engine Unicode issue
        # https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/pull/58
        approval_url = str(link.href)
        print("Redirect for approval: %s" % (approval_url))
```

I tried not to specify links for redirects. If they are not present, the payment is not created.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using a deprecated v1/payments API and corresponding SDK. If you were going to implement a website checkout, you should use the current v2/checkout/orders API and its SDK instead; such an integration is [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls)

But your invoice use case is not a normal website checkout, as you've noted. Indeed there is a separate Invoicing API for it, see [the invoicing integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/basic-integration/).

There's no SDK for invoicing APIs--use direct HTTPS API calls to first obtain an oauth2 access token and then create your invoice.

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand you correctly. I don't need to check any website. I want to create a money request. Did you mean that the payment does not work because of an outdated version of the sdk?

Comment: No -- I meant what I said, which is that you should use the Invoicing API.